# Why can we not say using the squeeze theorem that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)/x = 0$?

Tags: calculus

I understand that $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)/x$ is indeterminate. I don't know why it's wrong, however, to use that fact that $-1\le \sin(1/x) \le 1$ to say that the limit is $0$.

Also, is it possible to show the limit doesn't exist at $0$ without using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: I'm guess your proposed inequality is $-1/|x| \leq \sin(1/x)/x \leq 1/|x|$. Do the outer functions tend to $0$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: "to say that the limit is $0$": what ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Sorry, I was thinking of $\lim_{x\to \infty}$. So squeeze theorem doesn't work.

Comment: @H.H. So, does $x\to \infty$ or does $x\to 0$?  Please clarify and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MarkViola: The problem as stated is correct. What I meant in my comment above was that when I was thinking about using the squeeze theorem, I was mistakenly applying the limit $x\to \infty$ and then concluding that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Well the limit of interest fails to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_n=\frac1{n\pi} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ then

$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x_n}\right)}{x_n}=n\pi \cdot \sin(n\pi)= n\pi \cdot 0=0$$

and for $x_n=\frac1{2\pi n+ \frac\pi 2} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ then

$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x_n}\right)}{x_n}=\left(2\pi n+ \frac\pi 2\right) \cdot \sin\left(2\pi n+ \frac\pi 2\right)= \left(2\pi n+ \frac\pi 2\right) \cdot 1\to \infty$$

Squeeze theorem is useless indeed as $x>0$

$$-1\le \sin\left(\frac1{x}\right) \le 1 \implies -\frac 1x\le \frac{\sin\left(\frac1{x}\right)}{x} \le \frac1x$$

and $\frac1x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$$x=\frac{2}{\pi n}.$$

Comment: Thanks. We get $\frac{2}{\pi n} \lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})$. This diverges.

Comment: @H.H.: your expression is wrong. Pay attention.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The expression is wrong but by this choice the limit is $\infty$, it seems we are looking when the limit is zero.

Comment: @user: the expression in the comment is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes of course but $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{\pi n}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2}) =\infty$ and it seems the asker is looking for a limit to zero.

Comment: @user: read my answer again (it is not long).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I suspect I'm missing something!

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Oh, I think I see what I missed. $\sin(n \pi/2)$ alternates b/w the values $-1, 0$ and $1$. This means there is no limiting value, or that the limit doesn't exist as $x \to 0$. If you meant the simplified expression is wrong, then I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @H.H.: $n$ must be inside the limit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Absolutely; I was treating it as a constant. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @user: on second thoughts, your comments are completely surrealistic, as you are recommending the same technique !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed I was completely missing at first the point of the question and also for your answer. Sorry! Now it is clear.